# How do you retrieve the array adapter currently set for a spinner? Android OS, Droid

Tags: android, arrays, spinner, android-adapterview

Looking to create a menu toggle that switches between two possible arrays for a spinner. For example, if the spinner is set to show array A, then when I press this menu button, I want the spinner to be set to array B. If I press it again, I want it to be set back to array A.

I can handle the if/then statements and all, but how do I call the spinner's array adapter? I know how to call its value using getSelectedItemPosition(); but is there a similar method for retrieving WHICH array it is currently set to?

Answer (score 1):

I think `AdapterView#getAdapter()` is inherited by android.widget.Spinner?

Comment: Dev website says that getAdapter() returns a value of type "abstract T"

What is that and how can I assign a variable to it? Sorry, I'm a bit new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is that `AdapterView#getAdapter()` is an abstract method. You want to be using `AbsSpinner#getAdapter()` which is where getAdapter() is actually implemented. This will return a `SpinnerAdapter`.